# In React (with JSX), is there any way to pass a string as an event handler?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jsx

From [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), "With JSX you pass a function as the event handler, rather than a string."

However, I need to pass the string: `$("#w-nav-button").trigger("tap")` to trigger the custom jQuery "tap" event. I can't convert it into a function (e.g. `{() => $("#w-nav-button").trigger("tap")}`) because I did not import jQuery into the current file, and so Webpack fails to compile (`'$' is not defined`).

I need to use jQuery because I'm using a navbar which is generated by Webflow, and Webflow uses jQuery and its custom Javascript library, which has some incompatibility with React Router (I'm building a single-page application).

Comment: Even if you manage to pass that string into the event, it will not work because '$' will not magically be defined. You need to import jquery manually. Have a look at this https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: `onClick={() => window.$("#w-nav-button").trigger("tap")}`